# Getting 127.0.0.1 in request ip header

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nestjs, ip, request-headers

I have a NestJS server that is deployed on an EC2 instance with nginx. I want to get the client ip address from where request is originating but i get "127.0.0.1" as ip in every request no matter where its coming from.

i have tried getting ip directly from request headers and used @Ip decorator from nestjs as well. but still getting same ip.

i have tried setting headers in nginx config as well like this.

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using fastify or express under the hood of NestJS?

Comment: I am using express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main.ts`'s `bootstrap` method, add this line before `app.listen()`

```js
app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().set("trust proxy", true);
```

This will tell express to trust the proxy IPs and allow you to properly use `req.ip` or the `@Ip()` decorator